# Insert data attribute globally to all Rails form helpers (including destroy and button_to forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add an arbitrary HTML5 data attribute to all Rails-generated form tags (including those generated with form_for, destroy, button_to, and ideally form_tag.)  Not sure how to accomplish this.  I imagine it would have to do with monkey patching the form builder class?

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes this may have something to do with monkey patching the default form builder, but what are you trying to achieve here? Cause maybe there's a better solution...

Comment: Thanks for your response - better solutions are appreciated!  AJAX in JQM is nice, except for when forms are submitted.  For example, if an unauthenticated user visits a protected page (which then redirects to sign-in and friendly forwards back to requested page after signing in), the cache is not cleared and the page still looks like the user is not signed in (until the browser is refreshed).  Similar problems with error messages upon invalid form submits and ajax deletes.  I'd rather turn off AJAX for forms by default and then change the data attr in the rare case I want AJAX on form submit.